# How do I import an iCal feed to Twitter on an as-it-happens basis?

Tags: twitter, icalendar

I have an account on Twitter that I use for saying "what I'm doing." Some of my iCal feeds already know what I'm doing and I don't want to have to do double entry and record that event twice.

Is there a service (not unlike twitterfeed.com, which at the moment doesn't support iCal) that will post updates to Twitter from an iCal feed on an as-it-happens basis?

Comment: Where do your your iCal feeds come from ?

Comment: Meetup.com.  I just double checked, the RSS feeds of the calendars are upcoming events.  If there was an RSS feed of past events, I would be able to use that.  So iCal would still be the most elegant solution, if the translation tool existed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have access to a PHP web server and cron jobs, you could try and install [iCal-to-Twitter](http://github.com/si/iCal-to-Twitter)

Answer (score 2):

Google Calendar provides an RSS feed for every Calendar. It will be able to run in [Twitterfeed](http://twitterfeed.com/). I have a Twitter account running that does just that.